# R glmnet: segmentation fault when using multinomial and pmax

Tags: r, segmentation-fault, glmnet, multinomial

I use the `glmnet` package to run multinomial lasso regression. When using `family="multinomial` and a dataset with `p` variables and `n`samples and `pmax=x` a segmentation fault occurs if `x` is odd (if not `pmax>p`. In this case it is most probably ignored because it has no influence). An example:

```
n=100
p=20
require(glmnet)
D= as.data.frame(replicate(p, rnorm(n)))
D[,p] = as.factor(round(rnorm(n)))

lasso  <- glmnet(data.matrix(D[, -p]), D[, p], standardize=T, family="multinomial")         ## works
lasso  <- glmnet(data.matrix(D[, -p]), D[, p], standardize=T, family="multinomial", pmax=7) ## works, because it is odd
lasso  <- glmnet(data.matrix(D[, -p]), D[, p], standardize=T, family="multinomial", pmax=24 ## works, because pmax>p
lasso  <- glmnet(data.matrix(D[, -p]), D[, p], standardize=T, family="multinomial", pmax=10)## crashes
```

and the Error message:

```
 *** caught segfault ***
address 0x22de58a8, cause 'memory not mapped'

Traceback:
 1: .Fortran("lognet", parm = alpha, nobs, nvars, nc, as.double(x),     y, offset, jd, vp, cl, ne, nx, nlam, flmin, ulam, thresh,     isd, intr, maxit, kopt, lmu = integer(1), a0 = double(nlam *         nc), ca = double(nx * nlam * nc), ia = integer(nx), nin = integer(nlam),     nulldev = double(1), dev = double(nlam), alm = double(nlam),     nlp = integer(1), jerr = integer(1), PACKAGE = "glmnet")
 2: lognet(x, is.sparse, ix, jx, y, weights, offset, alpha, nobs,     nvars, jd, vp, cl, ne, nx, nlam, flmin, ulam, thresh, isd,     intr, vnames, maxit, kopt, family)
 3: glmnet(data.matrix(D[, -p]), D[, p], standardize = T, family = "multinomial",     pmax = 10)
```

my first question is: why? is there a mathematical reason for this? (I suppose so...)

the second one is: isn't there a better solution than a segmentation fault?...like a warning or so? Or just using `pmax<-pmax-1`

EDIT: ok, it seems to be a bit more complicated. Sometimes the segmentation fault only occurs if i execute the very same command with the same number for pmax a second time.

Additionally i found this error

```
*** glibc detected *** /usr/lib64/R/bin/exec/R: double free or corruption (out): 0x0000000005c41720 ***
======= Backtrace: =========
....
```

for both, even and odd, numbers for pmax....

Now it looks more like a bug for me....or?

EDIT 2:
I run R 2.15.2 with glmnet 1.9-5 in a linux environment (64 bit)
I also get a segmentation fault on a different PC with ubuntu 64 bit and R 3.0.2

Comment: I'm rather surprised the latest version of glmnet even functions with a 2.x version of R.  How's about you upgrade to get proper code?

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I get, under R 3.0.2,  64k,  Windows 7, glmnet1.9-5

```
lasso  <- glmnet(data.matrix(D[, -p]), D[, p], standardize=T, family="multinomial", pmax=10)
Warning message:
from glmnet Fortran code (error code -10005); Number of nonzero coefficients along the path exceeds pmax=10 at 5th lambda value; solutions for larger lambdas returned
```

You didn't state your setup so I can't commment on why you don't capture the error, but this message should give considerable insight :-) into why large pmax is causing trouble.

EDIT: to clarify:  I do not get a segfault.

Comment: sry, i add the system infos in the first post. no, this warning is completely normal. This is the reason for using pmax: not all values of lamda are used but only until a certain number of variables has non-zero coefficients. This warning occurs in my setup, too whenever no segmentation fault is thrown

Answer (score -1):

I know this answer is too late, but just in case someone may find the same issue:

I had the same problem, and solved it following the steps in [This Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39675664/using-glmnet-with-matlab-r2016a/). 
Basically, for any version of MATLAB you have got, try

```
mex -v -setup
```

which, when falling, would give a list of compilers to use. Install the more recent ones but not after the MATLAB version (for 2016a, I did XE2016 and VS2015). Then

```
mex glmnetMex.F glmnet.f
```

will do the job.

On a Linux machine (with 2014a), I tried

```
mex -largeArrayDims glmnetMex.F GLMnet.f
```

using the **gcc** compiler and it worked too.

Hope this might help. It has cost me weeks to figure this out.

Comment: this is an `R` question.