# Using glmnet with MATLAB R2016a

Tags: matlab, mex, glmnet

i'm trying to use `glmnet` vignette in MATLAB R2016a on windows 10 (64bit). I downloaded the version from [here](http://web.stanford.edu/~hastie/glmnet_matlab/index.html). Every time that I try to use a function (like `cvglmnet`) MATLAB crashes.

The glmnet version for MATLAB was tested only on MATLAB 2013b (64-bit), but I wanted to know if someone was able to use it on other versions of MATLAB and how to do that. I think the problem is the mex file that maybe should be recompiled since the error on the MATLAB crash says

```
This error was detected while a MEX-file was running. If the MEX-file
is not an official MathWorks function, please examine its source code
for errors. Please consult the External Interfaces Guide for information
on debugging MEX-files.
```

but I don't know how to do that.

Comment: You can find a set of pre-compiled files for 64-bit systems that is compatible with Windows 10 at https://github.com/growlix/glmnet_matlab

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem recompiling the Fortran files. To do that I installed Visual Studio 2015, then Intel Parallel Studio XE 2016 for Fortran (the 2017 version doesn't work) and then on MATLAB terminal I used:

```
mex glmnetMex.F glmnet.f
```